# return data that has the same index but different value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
name country gender
John CA      1
John DA      0
John SA      1
Wang DA      1
Liu  SA      0
Zhang SA     0
Zhang DA     1
```

I am hoping to return rows that have the same name but assign two gender values. If a name is assigned with both gender 0 and 1, we return them.

```
The returned frame is
John CA      1
John DA      0
John SA      1 
Zhang SA     0
Zhang DA     1
```

I used `groupby(['name', 'country'])['gender'].unique()`
but it returns

```
John CA [0,1]
```

Is there anyway I can return the frame?

Answer (score 1):

try this, thanks [`@ShubhamSharma`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12833166/shubham-sharma) for suggesting [`DataFrameGroupBy.nunique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.nunique.html#pandas-core-groupby-dataframegroupby-nunique)

```
count_ = df.groupby('name').gender.transform('nunique')

0    3
1    3
2    3
3    1
4    1
5    2
6    2
Name: gender, dtype: int64

mask = count_.gt(1) # create mask with count greater than 1

0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
4    False
5     True
6     True
Name: gender, dtype: bool

print(df[mask])
```

---

```
    name country  gender
0   John      CA       1
1   John      DA       0
2   John      SA       1
5  Zhang      SA       0
6  Zhang      DA       1
```

Comment: could you explain a little bit, what does count mean here, and what does gt(1) means here

Comment: Hey sushant, I think need `transform('nunique')` + `Series.eq(2)` :)

Comment: @ShubhamSharma, yes.. ``nunique`` makes more sense rather than ``count`` here.. thanks for the info.

Comment: @sushanth Now better ~

Answer (score 0):

Use `map` to create a filter and apply it to the original dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['John', 'John', 'John', 'Wang', 'Liu', 'Zhang', 'Zhang'], 'country': ['CA', 'DS', 'SA', 'DA', 'SA', 'SA', 'DA'], 'gender': [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0 ,1]})

# Filer names where both 0 and 1 values exist for gender column
df_filter = df.groupby(['name'])['gender'].unique().map(len) == 2

# Apply filer to original dataframe
df = df[df.apply(lambda r: df_filter.loc[r['name']], axis=1)]

print(df.to_string(index=False))

'''
Output:

name country  gender
John      CA       1
John      DS       0
John      SA       1
Zhang     SA       0
Zhang     DA       1

'''
```